# Simple ANTLR project test java class hangs

Tags: java, parsing, antlr3

Hello I've followed Scott Stanchfield's tutorial [ANTLR 3.x Creating and Executing a Grammar in Eclipse](http://vimeo.com/groups/29150/videos/8015802). However when I try to run the Test class the main method only reaches line 21 before hanging on line 22.

test class:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws RecognitionException {
    System.out.println("start!");
    CharStream charStream =  new ANTLRStringStream("once upon a time");
    XLLexer lexer = new XLLexer(charStream);
    TokenStream tokenStream = new LegacyCommonTokenStream(lexer);

    XLParser parser = new XLParser(tokenStream);
    System.out.println("in progress!");
    parser.rule();
    System.out.println("done!");

    }

}
```

and the output:

```
start!
in progress!
```

so it seems that the rule method in the XLParser class hangs.

here is my grammar file:

```
grammar XL;

options {
    language = Java;
}

@header {
    package com.slmyers.ANTLR;

}

rule: IDENT+;

IDENT : 'a'..'z'+;
WS : ' '+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

I run the interpreter and it seems to produce the proper output:

[image: interpreter output]

I'm not sure what the problem is and would appreciate any help provided. I did not provide the generated files, but will if it helps.

Comment: parser.rule(); sorry should've made that more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found problem:

`TokenStream tokenStream = new LegacyCommonTokenStream(lexer);`

should be:

`TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);`

derp